# Can't see my hard drive and can't repair it

Tags: mac

I can't see my hard drive on my desktop but I can see it on the left of my disc utility window , I can't  click the verify button or the repair ... Is there a way to repair it before I format it ?
Thx for ur help .

Comment: Are you talking about an external drive or the internal drive?  If external, you may need to press the Mount button at the top of the window.

Comment: It's external HD and I can't press on the mount button it's not dark blu